# Tabla no cambia tamaño de letra

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla construida desde un PHP tal que así:

```
$tabla ="<table class='table  table-condensed  table-striped text-center' >";
$tabla .="<thead>";
$tabla .= "<tr>";
$tabla .="<th>#</th>";
$tabla .="<th>Tarif</th>";
$tabla .="<th>Origen</th>";
$tabla .="<th>Destino</th>";
$tabla .="<th>Estado</th>";
$tabla .="</tr>";
$tabla .="</thead>";
//Cuerpo de la tabla
$tabla .="<tbody>";

try { 
    //pasar la consulta a la conexion
    $resultado=$conn->prepare($sql1);     
    $resultado->execute();


    while($row = $resultado->fetch()) {


        $datos=$row[0]."/".$row[10]."/".$row[11]."/".$row[8]."/".$row[9];

        $tabla .="<tr>";
        $tabla .='<td>'. $row[7].'</td>';
        $tabla .='<td>'. $row[8].'</td>';
        $tabla .='<td>'. $row[2].'</td>';
        $tabla .='<td>'. $row[3].'</td>';
        $tabla .='<td><button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVerBillete" onclick="cargaDatos(\''.$datos.'\')"></button></td>';
        $tabla .="</tr>";
    }
    //cierre del cuerpo y de la tabla
    $tabla .="</tbody>";
    $tabla .="</table>";

    echo $tabla;
```

Quiero cambiar el tamaño de la letra tanto de cabeceras como de celdas pero no lo consigo con una hoja de estilos.

La tabla se carga en un div HTML de esta manera:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="contenidoTabla">
     <!-- Aqui va la tabla -->

</div>
```

He probado a poner en una hoja de estilos:

```
#contenidoTabla{
font-size: 5px; 
}

td{
font-size: 5px; 
}

th{
font-size: 5px; 
}
```

Pero no cambia nada. Agradecería alguna sugerencia.
Gracias.

Comment: Estas usando `Bootstrap`, ¿cierto?. Si es así, ¿qué versión?

Comment: Es la versión 4

Comment: Es probable que alguna otra regla tenga prioridad sobre las que has creado. Intenta agregando `!important` a las que menciones, es decir, `font-size: 5px !important;`. Si funciona quiere decir que es lo que he dicho, si no funciona, puede ser que no estés cargando correctamente tu hoja de estilos.

Answer (score 2):

El CSS funciona, como podrás ver más adelante en la prueba.

Si no te funciona es porque:

1. No estás poniendo la tabla donde va. Podrías hacer esto, para no estar abriendo y cerrando bloques de código:

   ```
   #Abrimos el div
   echo '<div class="container-fluid" id="contenidoTabla">';

       # ... codigo PHP que crea y llena la tabla
       #Debes imprimir la tabla dentro de este bloque div
       echo $tabla; 

   #Cerramos el div
   echo '</div>';
   ```

   Para que sea más fácil quizá puedes concatenar también el `div` en la variable.
2. No estás agregando correctamente el CSS.

#### Prueba

He cambiado *ad libitum* algunos valores como tamaño de letras y colores, sólo para que veas que funciona.

```css
#contenidoTabla {
  font-size: 15px;
}

td {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
}

th {
  font-size: 25px;
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="contenidoTabla">
  <table class="table  table-condensed  table-striped text-center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Tarif</th>
        <th>Origen</th>
        <th>Destino</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVerBillete"></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿No deberíamos simplemente comentar que el código si funciona y que lo que plantea no se puede reproducir? ¿Y quizás pedirle más información? Digo... en principio no estás respondiendo realmente la pregunta. Es más **estoy casi seguro de que el problema son los estilos de `Bootstrap`**

Comment: Hola. La tabla va a ese div con un Ajax que la trae del PHP y se carga perfectamente. ¿podría estar relacionado con el orden en el que se carga el código?. A la hoja de estilos la llamo en el Header y la tabla aparece mas tarde. Quiero decir que la tabla no se carga al abrir la página, sino al interactuar con un botón. No se, por dar ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Pues mira por donde tiene que ser cosa de los estilos del Bootstrap.
Lo he solucionado añadiendo el tamaño de letra dentro la linea de definición de la tabla:

```
$tabla ="<table class='table  table-condensed  table-striped text-center' style='font-size: 5px;> ";
```

De esta manera lo toma perfectamente.

Comment: Seria bueno poder determinar exactamente porque no puedes sobrescribir los estilos con `CSS`. Pero, si esta solución te satisface, enhorabuena!. Recuerda que puedes marcar tu respuesta como la más acertada.

Comment: Si, seria bueno pero no tengo capacidad para ello. Me he dado cuenta de que al hacerlo así desaparece la cabecera de la tabla. Otro misterio.

Comment: Es porque te falta cerrar las comillas simples. Es decir, `style='font-size: 5px;'` <-- esta comilla